# How to add comment box to page?

Tags: objective-c, ios, textbox

I am trying to model my "add comment" interface with what you see in the diagram below. However, I was unable to find such a UI element in the XCode library.

Is this a customized UI element? Or can I find a UI with the same look and feel as what you see in the diagram?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approximate it using a UIImageView (the silver gray background) and a UITextView on top of it which has a proper cornerRadius set. You'll need to:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

in order to be able to set the cornerRadius property of the UITextView like this:

```
    textView.layer.cornerRadius = 1.0f; // play around to see what gives you the above rounded effect to your needs.
```

Comment: Cool, so this really requires customization. Thanks for the advise!

Comment: This is what came off the top of my head. It looks like a UISearchBar but clearly its not what you're looking for. So I guess this is the simplest and closest approximation to achieve the above effect for a simple comment box.

Comment: Any way to create the shadow effect as well?

Comment: Yah I was looking at the UISearchbar, but didn't fit what I wanted.

Comment: There are quite a few properties related to shadow in textView.layer. Check them out.

Comment: @Zhen you can get much closer to your look by putting a clear textview on top of an image...

Comment: like textView.layer.shadowPath, textView.layer.shadowOpacity, textView.layer.shadowColor, textView.layer.shadowOffset and textView.layer.shadowRadius

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you just want the textfield shape, you can use a UIImageView as background and have a textfield or textview on top of it accordingly...Now if you want that textview to expand thats another story, you can use strechableImageWithleftCapWidth: method on the image in order to be able to strech and expand it, and then you would need to create a custom UITextView class that expands as characters are typed in...